# Finding the center of mass of a cylinder

Tags: calculus, optimization

Help finding center of mass of soda can?

If you represent the soda can as a right-circular cylinder

radius=$4$ cm height =$12$ cm

We are told to neglect the mass of the can itself.

When the can is full the center of mass is at $6$ cm above the base, halfway along the axis of the can.
As the can is drained and air replaces the soda, the center of mass descends towards the bottom.
However when the can is completely empty the center of mass is still at $6$ cm.
Assuming the density of soda is $1$ gram per cubic cm and the density of air is $0.001$ gram per cubic cm.

Find the depth of soda in the can for which the center of mass is at it's lowest point.

I really do not know where to begin on this mess.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

When the surface is at height $h$ from the bottom, hence height $H-h$ from the top, the gravity center of the soda is at $\dfrac h2$ and that of air at $h+\dfrac{H-h}2=\dfrac{H+h}2$.

The height of the global gravity center is the average of these two heights, weighted by the weights of the two parts.

$$h_g=\frac{d_sh}{d_sh+d_a(H-h)}\frac h2+\frac{d_a(H-h)}{d_sh+d_a(H-h)}\frac{H+h}2=\frac12\frac{(d_s-d_a)h^2+d_aH^2}{(d_s-d_a)h+d_aH}\\
=\frac12\frac{\delta\left(\dfrac hH\right)^2+1}{\delta\dfrac hH+1}=\frac12\left(\delta\dfrac hH-1\right)+\frac1{\delta\dfrac hH+1}.$$

Find the root of the derivative of this expression.

Answer (score 2):

A simple approach is to argue that the center of mass must be at the top of the liquid.  At that point, and only that point, if you add more liquid to the can it goes above the center of mass and raises it.  If you take liquid out of the can it comes from below the center of mass, raising it.  Now you don't need to take a differential at all.  Let the height of soda be $h$.  The cm of the soda is at $h/2$ and the mass is $4 \pi h$.  The cm of the air is at $(12+h)/2$ and the mass is $0.001 \cdot 4 \pi (12-h)$  The overall cm is then $4 \pi h \frac h2 + \frac {((12+h)/2)0.001 \cdot 4 \pi (12-h)}{4 \pi h+0.001 \cdot 4 \pi (12-h)}$, which has to equal $h$ and you have a quadratic.

Answer (score 1):

Center of mass is found by taking *moments* with respect to to bottom line of cylinder. As prismatic volume is proportional to cylinder cross section area the radius of cylinder plays no role, being a constant.

$$ h_{Center \;of \;mass} \;= \bar {h}= \frac{\gamma_a.h. (H-h/2)+\gamma_s.(H-h)^2/2}{\gamma_a.h+\gamma_s(H-h)} \tag 1 $$

[image]

*Checks*

$$ @h=0,\bar {h}= H/2\quad @ h=H,\bar {h}= H/2; \text{ is ok for all density combinations }$$

Position of center of mass from top

$$\bar {h}=\frac{\gamma_a(hH-h^2/2)+\gamma_s(H-h)^2/2}{\gamma_ah + \gamma_s(H-h) }\tag 2 $$

To minimize cm position we differentiate w.r.t $h$ and by Quotient Rule

$$=\frac{\gamma_a(h-H)+\gamma_s(2 h -2 H)/2}{\gamma_a- \gamma_s }= (H-h) \tag 3 $$

$$\gamma_a(hH-h^2/2) + \gamma_s(h-H)^2/2= \gamma_a.h.(H-h)+\gamma_s (H-h)^2 \tag 4 $$

Simplifying,

$$ \frac{\gamma_a}{\gamma_s}=\frac{(H-h)^2}{h^2} \tag 5 $$
so that the required fractional soda column depth

$$ \frac{(H-h)}{H}=\frac{\sqrt{\gamma_a/\gamma_s} }{1+\sqrt{\gamma_a/\gamma_s} } ;\tag 6 $$

Evaluating for $(H=12,\gamma_a= 0.001,\gamma_s=1),  {(H-h)}\approx 0.367841 $ that gives soda depth seen in graph as the minimum.

Air depth is $12-0.367841= 11.632159$ cm;

Equation 1) is plotted and same 6 cm are found for fully filled and fully empty cases:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

suppose soda is at height of h and rest of volume fill with air(ie.12-h)
hence $CoM=\frac{\sum{HVD}}{\sum{VD}}$ where $H$ is height of CoM of each subtance and V is volume and $d$ is density,

here sfter simplification it become $x_h=\frac{1*h*\frac{h}{2} + .001*(12-h)(6+\frac{h}{2})}{1*h + 0.001*(12-h)}$ and after that apply maxima minima condition (ie.$\frac{dx_h}{dh}=0$) to get $h_{min}$ and apply it in orginal equatio to get lowest position of CoM,Hope you got the idea :)

Answer (score 0):

Unless the function for the location of the center of mass is specifically needed, we can just consider the change in the center of mass itself as liquid leaves the container.  Also, if the cross-section of the container is uniform, its area $ \ A \ $ and shape are of no importance in the analysis.  (Neither does it matter whether the axis of symmetry is perpendicular to the container's base, as long as the angle to the base is constant ["Cavalieri's Principle"].)

We will call $ \ x \ $ the depth of the liquid; $ \ H \ \ , $ the height of the container; $ \ c \ \ , $ the height of the center of mass above the base; $ \ \rho_L \ \ , $ the density of the liquid; and $ \ \rho_G \ \ , $ the density of the gas.  A convenient way to treat the physical situation is to "split" it into the entire container filled with gas of mass $ \ \rho_G·H·A \ $ with a center of mass *always* at $ \ \frac{H}{2} \ $ and a "superimposed" varying mass  $ \ (\rho_L - \rho_G)·x·A \ $ with its center of mass located at $ \ \frac{x}{2} \ \ . $  The center of *total* mass is then a "weighted average" of these two centers of mass, located at
$$ c \ \ = \ \ \frac{(\rho_L - \rho_G)·x·A · (x/2) \ + \ \rho_G·H·A · (H/2)}{(\rho_L - \rho_G)·x·A   \ + \ \rho_G·H·A}  \ \ = \ \ \frac{\frac{1}{H}·\left( 1 - \frac{\rho_G}{\rho_L}  \right)·x^2 \ + \ \frac{\rho_G}{\rho_L} · H}{\frac{2}{H}·\left( 1 - \frac{\rho_G}{\rho_L}  \right)·x   \ + \ 2·\frac{\rho_G}{\rho_L}} \ \ , $$
demonstrating that the cross-sectional area of the container is irrelevant.  We observe that this has the proper behavior at the "ends" of its domain in that for $ \ x \ = \ 0 \ $ ("empty" container) and $ \ x \ = \ H \  $ ("full"), the center of total mass is given as $ \ c \ = \ \frac{H}{2} \ \ . $

The extremal value for $ \ c \ $ is reached when $ \ \frac{dc}{dx} \ = \ 0 \ \ . $  It is easier to deal with this calculation by differentiating $ \ c \ $ implicitly with respect to $ \ x \ \ , $ writing the function as $ \ c \ = \ \frac{\mathcal{N}}{\mathcal{D}} \ \ : $

$$ \frac{d}{dx} \ [ \ c·\mathcal{D} \ ] \ \ = \ \ \frac{d}{dx} \ \mathcal{N} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \frac{dc}{dx}  · \mathcal{D} \ + \ c·\frac{d \mathcal{D}}{dx}   \ \ = \ \ \frac{d \mathcal{N}}{dx} \ \ . $$
On setting   $ \ \frac{dc}{dx} \ = \ 0 \ \ , $  we obtain (after multiplying through by $ \ \mathcal{D} \ \ , $ which is never zero since it is the total mass in the container)
$$    \mathcal{N}   ·  \frac{d \mathcal{D}}{dx}   \ - \ \mathcal{D}  ·  \frac{d \mathcal{N}}{dx} \ \ = \ \ 0 $$ $$ \Rightarrow \ \ \left[ \ \frac{1}{H}·\left( 1 - \frac{\rho_G}{\rho_L}  \right)·x^2 \ + \ \frac{\rho_G}{\rho_L} · H \ \right] · \frac{2}{H}·\left( 1 - \frac{\rho_G}{\rho_L}  \right) $$ $$ - \ \left[ \ \frac{2}{H}·\left( 1 - \frac{\rho_G}{\rho_L}  \right)·x   \ + \ 2·\frac{\rho_G}{\rho_L} \ \right] · \frac{2}{H}·\left( 1 - \frac{\rho_G}{\rho_L}  \right)·x \ \ = \ \ 0 $$
$$ \Rightarrow \ \   \left( 1 - \frac{\rho_G}{\rho_L}  \right)·x^2 \ + \ \frac{\rho_G}{\rho_L} · H^2  \  - \    2 ·\left( 1 - \frac{\rho_G}{\rho_L}  \right)·x^2   \ + \ 2·\frac{\rho_G}{\rho_L}   ·  H·x \ \ = \ \ 0 $$
$$ \Rightarrow \ \   \left( 1 - \frac{\rho_G}{\rho_L}  \right)·x^2 \ - \ 2·\frac{\rho_G}{\rho_L} · H·x \ - \  \frac{\rho_G}{\rho_L} · H^2   \ \ = \ \ 0 \ \ , $$
where we have divided the equation through by a few non-zero factors.

The solutions to this quadratic equation are
$$ x \ \ = \ \ \frac{-\frac{\rho_G}{\rho_L} · H  \ \pm \ H·\sqrt{\frac{\rho_G}{\rho_L}}}{\left( 1 - \frac{\rho_G}{\rho_L}  \right)} \ \ , $$
for which the physically meaningful positive value is
$$ x_{min} \ \ = \ \ \left(\frac{\sqrt{\frac{\rho_G}{\rho_L}} \ - \ \frac{\rho_G}{\rho_L} }{  1 - \frac{\rho_G}{\rho_L}  }\right)  ·  H \ \ . $$

Inserting the quantities given in the problem statement, we find that the center of total mass in the container is lowest at the liquid depth of
$$ x_{min} \ \ = \ \ \left(\frac{\sqrt{0.001} \ - \ 0.001 }{  0.999  }\right)  ·  12 \ \ \approx \ \ 0.0307 · 12 \ \ \approx \ \ 0.368 \ \text{cm.} \ \ . $$

$$ \ \ $$
Apropos of **Ross Millikan**'s answer, when we use this result for $ \ x \ $ in our center-of-total-mass expression, we have (writing $ \ \mathbf{r} \ $ for $ \ \frac{\rho_G}{\rho_L} \ $ )
$$ c|_{x_{min}} \ \ =  \ \ \frac{\frac{1}{H}·\left( 1 - \mathbf{r}  \right)·\left(\frac{\sqrt{\mathbf{r}} \ - \ \mathbf{r} }{  1 - \mathbf{r}  }\right)^2  ·  H^2 \ + \ \mathbf{r} · H}{\frac{2}{H}·\left( 1 - \mathbf{r}  \right)·\left(\frac{\sqrt{\mathbf{r}} \ - \ \mathbf{r} }{  1 - \mathbf{r}  }\right)  ·  H   \ + \ 2·\mathbf{r}} \ \ =  \ \ \frac{\frac{\left(\sqrt{\mathbf{r}} \ - \ \mathbf{r}\right)^2 }{  1 - \mathbf{r}  }  ·  H \ + \ \mathbf{r} · \left(\frac{1 - \mathbf{r} }{  1 - \mathbf{r}  }\right) · H}{2·\left(\sqrt{\mathbf{r}} \ - \ \mathbf{r} \right)   \ + \ 2·\mathbf{r}}  $$
$$ =  \ \ \frac{\left(\sqrt{\mathbf{r}} \ - \ \mathbf{r}\right)^2   \ + \ \mathbf{r} · \left(1 - \mathbf{r} \right)}{2·\sqrt{\mathbf{r}}·\left(1 - \mathbf{r} \right)} \ · \ H \ \  = \ \ \frac{\mathbf{r} \ - \ 2·\mathbf{r}·\sqrt{\mathbf{r}} \ + \  \mathbf{r}^2   \ + \ \mathbf{r} \ -  \  \mathbf{r}^2}{2·\sqrt{\mathbf{r}}·\left(1 - \mathbf{r} \right)} \ · \ H $$ $$ = \ \ \frac{2·\mathbf{r} \ - \ 2·\mathbf{r}·\sqrt{\mathbf{r}} }{2·\sqrt{\mathbf{r}}·\left(1 - \mathbf{r} \right)} \ · \ H \ \  = \ \ \frac{\sqrt{\mathbf{r}} \ - \ \mathbf{r} }{1 - \mathbf{r} } \ · \ H \ \ . $$

So the center-of-total-mass does indeed coincide with the surface of the liquid when it is at its lowest point.  The mass of liquid in the container is still far larger than the mass of gas at that moment (by about $ \ 32 \ $ times for the values in this problem), but the (first) moments of these masses about the liquid surface are equal:

$$ ( \ \rho_L \ · \ x_{min} \ ) \ · \ \frac{x_{min}}{2} \ \ =^{?} \ \ ( \ \rho_G \ · \ [H-x_{min}] \ ) \ · \ \frac{H-x_{min}}{2} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ x_{min}^2 \ \ =^{?} \ \  \mathbf{r} \ · \ (H \ - \ x_{min})^2   $$
$$ \Rightarrow \ \ \left[ \ \frac{\sqrt{\mathbf{r}} \ - \ \mathbf{r} }{1 - \mathbf{r} } \ · \ H \ \right]^2 \ \ =^{?} \ \   \mathbf{r} \ · \ \left( \ H \ - \ \left[ \ \frac{\sqrt{\mathbf{r}} \ - \ \mathbf{r} }{1 - \mathbf{r}} \ · \ H \ \right] \ \right)^2   $$
$$ \Rightarrow \ \ \left( \ \sqrt{\mathbf{r}} \ - \ \mathbf{r} \ \right)^2 \ \ =^{?} \ \  \mathbf{r} \ · \ \left[ \ \left(1 - \mathbf{r} \right) \ - \ \left( \ \sqrt{\mathbf{r}} \ - \ \mathbf{r}  \ \right) \ \right]^2   $$
$$ \Rightarrow \ \ \left( \ \sqrt{\mathbf{r}} \ - \ \mathbf{r} \ \right)^2 \ \ =^{!} \ \  \mathbf{r} \ · \ \left( \ 1 \  - \  \sqrt{\mathbf{r}} \  \right) ^2  \ \ . $$

Returning to the "two-component" description of the "container full of gas" and a variable portion of depth $ \ x \ $ and density $ \ \rho_L - \rho_G \ \ , $
$$ c \ \ =  \ \ \frac{\frac{1}{H}·( 1 - \mathbf{r} )·x^2 \ + \ \mathbf{r} · H}{\frac{2}{H}·( 1 - \mathbf{r} )·x   \ + \ 2·\mathbf{r}} \ \ , $$
we can understand the behavior of the center-of-total-mass.  When the depth of liquid is $ \ x \ \approx \ x_{min} \ \ , $ a small increase in depth changes the total-mass-moment by only a slightly larger factor than the total mass in the container increases, so $ \ c \ $ increases by a *very* small factor.  When $ \ x \ $ is significantly larger than $ \ x_{min} \ , $ the mass-moment and the mass of liquid dominate those of the gas, leading to  $ c \ \rightarrow \ \frac{\frac{1}{H}·( 1 - \mathbf{r} )·x^2 }{\frac{2}{H}·( 1 - \mathbf{r} )·x  } \ = \ \frac12·x \ \ ; \ $ we see this in the graph in **Narasimham**'s answer (adjusting for the use of $ \ H - x \ = \ 12 - x \ $ as the abscissa there).  For $ \ x \ < \ x_{min} \   $ being much smaller than $ \ H \ $ and $ \ \mathbf{r} \ >> \ 1 \ \ , $ the *quadratic* dependence on $ \ x \ $ of the mass-moment of the liquid component actually causes the total mass-moment to decrease more slowly than the mass of the liquid, and thus the total mass, with its linear dependence on $ \ x \ \ . \ $  Consequently, the ratio for $ \ c \ $ increases as the last of the liquid "drains out", tending to $ c \ \rightarrow \ \frac{0 \ + \ \mathbf{r} · H}{0  \ + \ 2·\mathbf{r}} \ = \ \frac{H}{2} \ \ . $  (Describing the process in words, somewhat glibly, the center of mass of the container "full" or "empty"  is the same $ \ \frac{H}{2} \ ; \ $ since the liquid has a far higher density than the gas, its mass-moment largely determines the total-center-of-mass until it is nearly gone; as the mass-moment of the gas becomes dominant, the total-center-of-mass "rapidly" returns to $ \ \frac{H}{2} \ \ . $  It was attempting to make sense of this latter part that interested me in the problem.)